# GCP Query - how to write year difference?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am rewriting hive query to GCP query where I think i'm failing in this portion.

`(year(CURRENT_DATE) - birth_year BETWEEN 13 AND 15)`

How can I rewrite that so it works in GCP environment? Basically I want the difference between current year and birth year column to be between 13 - 15.  Note that birth_year column is varchar (i.e 2004). Currently I am getting this error.

`line 6:22: '-' cannot be applied to bigint, varchar`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you need to cast to int64

`(year(CURRENT_DATE) - cast(birt_year as int64) BETWEEN 13 AND 15)`

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the string to a number before doing arithmetics:

```
year(CURRENT_DATE) - cast(birth_year as int64) between 13 and 15
```

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery:

```
(extract(year from CURRENT_DATE) - birth_year) BETWEEN 13 AND 15
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `fhoffa.x.age()`:

```sql
SELECT fhoffa.x.age('1989-11-9')
  , fhoffa.x.age('1989-11-9 23:01:01 America/Los_Angeles')


# 30.21917808219178
# 30.216438356164385
```

Since you only have a string with birth year, you can do this:

```sql
SELECT fhoffa.x.age(CONCAT(year_from_db, '-01-01'))
FROM (SELECT '1989' year_from_db)

# 31.076712328767123
```

You can use this function freely, I created it with this code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `fhoffa.x.age`(birth ANY TYPE) AS (
  DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), DATE(TIMESTAMP(birth)), YEAR)
  # the next line gives you the fraction of this year in days/365
   + DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE() , DATE_ADD(DATE(TIMESTAMP(birth)), INTERVAL (DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), DATE(TIMESTAMP(birth)), YEAR)) YEAR), DAY) / 365
);
```